# how to catch hex2bin() warning

Tags: php

Came across this today, not sure how to solve it.

I want to catch an `E_WARNING` level error issued by [hex2bin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php).

I thought I might be able to use a [try()catch()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) exception method but it did not work.

```php
try {
    $foo = hex2bin($bar);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Custom message');
}
```

The standard E_WARNING that is issued is, of course:

> Warning: hex2bin(): Input string must be hexadecimal string

In this particular situation I do **not** want to use the standard methods to disable errors, such as:

```
error_reporting(-1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Nor do I want to suppress the error using a `@hex2bin` method.

I actually *want* to have a custom error displayed, but I just do not seem to be able to find a way to catch when `hex2bin` throws an error.

Comment: Warnings are not errors. And they're not exceptions either. Rejecting the very language constructs meant to capture them seems silly. And what "custom error" do you want to display anyway (when feeding it invalid/unasserted data)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the input value to verify that it is hex before passing it to the hex2bin method.

```
if (ctype_xdigit($bar) && strlen($bar) % 2 == 0) {
    $foo = hex2bin($bar);
} else {
    //display error here
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 1 minute :D

Comment: Hey @mackers thanks. I came across the `ctype_xdigit` method before I was just hoping there was another method out there. Suppose it works so will just go ahead with it.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php), `hex2bin` returns:

> the binary representation of the given data or FALSE on failure.

That means you can do something like this if you want to use it in a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
  $foo = @hex2bin($bar);
  if(false === $foo) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid hexedecimal value.");
  }
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
}
```

Yes, `hex2bin` is suppressed. You can remove the `@` if you set `error_reporting` to suppress warnings.

Alternatively, you can check the type of `$foo` with `ctype_xdigit()` prior to using `hex2bin()`.